# How to write Google DataFlow templates in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-dataflow, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm looking for information on writing DataFlow jobs in NodeJS. The [tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts) are all referring to Java or Python.

Any ideas if it's possible?

Comment: Do you want to write a Dataflow job by NodeJS or send a Dataflow API call to create a job by NodeJS?

Comment: Write a Dataflow job. I understand it's not possible ATM since Apache Beam only supports Java + Python.

Comment: Yes. It is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until now(2.13.0), Beam allows writing pipeline by Python, Java and Go.

Beam community is working on cross language pipeline feature that allows call PTransforms written in another language, but NodeJS is not on the roadmap.

Check[1] for more information on it.

[1] https://beam.apache.org/roadmap/portability

Answer (score 0):

There is support for TypeScript now.

As of February 2023. it's still experimental but main functionality is covered, from [Apache Beam documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/):

> The Typescript SDK supports Node v16+ and is still experimental.

You can install it via npm:

```
npm install apache-beam
```

More instructions and documentation can be found in the official sites at npm and github.

Link npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/apache-beam

Link github (example): https://github.com/apache/beam-starter-typescript